# form action wordpress and php

Tags: forms, contact

I have this code to submit a contact form inside a wordpress page. The problem is that I'm not experienced with the WP api and I can't find a simple way to submit the form. Can anyone help me? I was using the form `action` but this way don't work.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 

if( $_POST['send_message'] ){

  $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

  $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );

  $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

  $to = 'demomail@demo.org';
  $subject = 'Info request from'. $name .'dal sito demo.com';

  $headers = 'From: info@demo.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: '.$email.' . "\r\n"';

  mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

}


?>

<!-- page cover -->
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID); ?>');" id="contact-cover-wrapper">
  <div class="container" id="">
    <h1 class="scroll-icon text-center animated infinite slideInDown slow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h1>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container" id="contact-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
<?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

      <from action="<?php get_permalink( $post->ID ) ?>" method="POST" id="">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
        <br>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
        <br>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="message" placeholder="Messagearea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="send_message" class="btn btn-outline-warning text-uppercase"><?php _e('Send') ?></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_template_part('assets/contacts'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

EDIT: I was made a typo error. Instead of `form` I wrote `from`. Now the submit button works, I need only to test if messages are forwarded correctly. It's seems that the messages are blocked by the hosting provider, do I need to configure something in wp? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WordPress, you shouldn't send POST requests directly to current URL. There [is an API to process such requests](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)).

So how should that be done?

First of all, you should send request to `admin-ajax.php`:

So instead of this:

```
<from action="<?php get_permalink( $post->ID ) ?>" method="POST" id="">
```

You should have this (also, there was a typo in 'form' word):

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_attr( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="POST" id="">  // changed URL
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_custom_form_submit" />  // action, because WP needs that
```

Then you have to register your actions that will process this form:

```
function my_custom_form_submit_process_callback() {
    $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
    $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $to = 'demomail@demo.org';
    $subject = 'Info request from'. $name .'dal sito demo.com';

    $headers = 'From: info@demo.com' . "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: '.$email.' . "\r\n"';

    mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );  // <- you should use wp_mail instead

    wp_redirect( '<URL>' );  // <- replace with proper url that should be visible after sending the form;
    die;
}
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_my_custom_form_submit', 'my_custom_form_submit_process_callback' );  // for anonymous users
add_action( 'admin_post_my_custom_form_submit', 'my_custom_form_submit_process_callback' );  // for logged in users
```

Comment: So there isn't a way using the plain php to handle this?

Comment: This is plain PHP. Although you should put PHP code directly in template files - it's considered a bad practice and make your theme hard to maintain.

Comment: I'm relatively new to wp themes development. Anyway, I've tried the code you suggested, but the form isn't submitted

Comment: My bad, there was a typo in 'admin_url'

Comment: fixed, but it's like the POST request isn't made

Comment: It's like the button didn't submit the form

Comment: It's hard to say, what's wrong. You may have some JS that is blocking it, or maybe there's a typo somewhere in your code.

Comment: There is no JS google maps a part in the contacts template part.